# Chat/1:1 Chat in Quickblox Chat sdk

Tags: android, quickblox

How to get Offline and online user in quickblox private chat between two user.
If two user Jone and kally if kally is offline than how to get status of offline user Kally my code here. Please check and help me.

```
         try {
            QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
            chatMessage.setBody(inputbox.getText().toString()); 
            chatMessage.setProperty("save_to_history", "1"); 
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
            chatMessage.setProperty("date_sent", time + "");
            privateChat.sendMessage(chatMessage);
            showMessage(chatMessage);
            inputbox.setText("");
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            Log.e("XMPPException",e.toString());
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            Log.e("Not Connected Exception",e.toString());
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e("NullPointerException", e.toString());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }

       QBPrivateChatManagerListener privateChatManagerListener = new              QBPrivateChatManagerListener() {
    @Override
    public void chatCreated(final QBPrivateChat privateChat, final boolean createdLocally) {
        if(!createdLocally){
            privateChat.addMessageListener(privateChatMessageListener);
        }
    }
};

QBMessageListener<QBPrivateChat> privateChatMessageListener = new QBMessageListener<QBPrivateChat>() {
    @Override
    public void processMessage(QBPrivateChat privateChat, final QBChatMessage chatMessage) {
        Log.w(Tag, "new incoming message: chatMessage" + chatMessage);
        showMessage(chatMessage);
        playBeepSound(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void processError(QBPrivateChat privateChat, QBChatException error, QBChatMessage originMessage){
        Log.w(Tag, "new incoming message: originMessage" + originMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void processMessageDelivered(QBPrivateChat privateChat, String messageID){
        Log.w(Tag, "new incoming message:messageID " + messageID);
    }

    @Override
    public void processMessageRead(QBPrivateChat privateChat, String messageID){
        Log.w(Tag, "new incoming message:messageID messageID" + messageID);
    }
};
private void createNewDialog(){
    privateChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();
    privateChatManager.createDialog(opponentId, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {
            //Log.e("QBdialog", ""+dialog);
            //Log.e("id", dialog.getDialogId());
            setUpListener();
            isQBDialog = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            Log.e("errors", ""+errors);
            isQBDialog = false;

        }
    });
}

private void setUpListener(){
privateChatManager.addPrivateChatManagerListener(privateChatManagerListener);
    privateChat = privateChatManager.getChat(opponentId);
    if (privateChat == null) {
        privateChat = privateChatManager.createChat(opponentId, privateChatMessageListener);
        privateChat.addIsTypingListener(privateChatIsTypingListener);

    }else{
        privateChat.addMessageListener(privateChatMessageListener);
        privateChat.addIsTypingListener(privateChatIsTypingListener);
    }
}
```

i am follow link for chat
http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to implement quickblox chat for one on one chat, which then I got stuck as the documentation is not so sufficient. Then I found out socket.io which is more convenient for one on one chat.follow the link: http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/.  You also have to find a free node.js hosting company. I can suggest you the heroku.com

Answer (score 0):

You can add listener for tracking users statuses - RosterListener.

For example:

https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/blob/master/Q-municate_core/src/main/java/com/quickblox/q_municate_core/qb/helpers/QBFriendListHelper.java

Q-municate tracks users statuses in real time (private and group chats).